# Optimize code for use gpu acceleration in matlab to factorize a matrix

Tags: matlab, gpu

I'm trying to improve my numerical method with gpu acceleration. I have this code for cholesky Incomplete factorization.

```
function [L]=CholeskyInc(A)
[n,m]=size(A);
if n~= m; error('A no es cuadrada');
else
    L=speye(n,n);
    for k=1:n
       L(k,k)=sqrt(A(k,k));
       for i=k+1:n
           if A(i,k)~=0
               L(i,k)=A(i,k)/A(k,k);
           end
       end
       for j=k+1:n
           for i=j:n
               if (A(i,j))~=0
                   L(i,j)=A(i,j)-A(i,k)*A(j,k);
               end
           end
       end
    end
end
```

This code work well and I started to move to GPU functions. the first change that I made was replace   **L=speye(n,n)** to **gpuArray(speye(n,n))** but gpuArrays don't suport indexing. ¿Does anyone have idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to SO! Are you trying to use the GPU to improve run times? If so, have you tried benchmarking your CPU code against the built-in [`ichol()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ichol.html) first? (`ichol()` does not work with `gpuArray`s, though.)

Comment: Hi @Vicky actually no because is part of the project of my numeric course use my own version of this factorization. I already finished my project but I researching about improve my code using the GPU

Comment: I'm not sure if GPU hardware is generally optimized for sparse operations, but as far as I understand, MATLAB only started supporting sparse `gpuArray`s at all in R2015a. Maybe in a few years Mathworks will add support for entrywise operations? Meanwhile, you might want to check out the CUDA sparse matrix library (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html). From the perspective of someone who's trying to learn by doing, it might be more efficient to avoid the MATLAB--GPU--sparse--entrywise combination and write the critical part of your program in C++/CUDA, I suppose.